# How do you change a filename once uploaded in Loopback?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to assign a profile picture to a user, I am currently trying to do this by uploading a file using the angular file-upload and then renaming it to the id of the user.

Is this

1. the best way to do this
2. if not how what is a better way

I just started looking at making a relation of a file belonging to one user but im not sure where the resources are to look for this

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How do you have this set up in Loopback? Can you show us what you have so far? That might help us answer the question(s).

Answer (score 0):

Create a newfile datasource.development.js and set NODE_ENV=development

```
module.exports = {
  'storageDs': {
    'name': 'storageDs',
    'connector': 'loopback-component-storage',
    'provider': 'filesystem',
    'root': './test/storageTesting',
    'maxFileSize': 20971520,
    'getFilename': function(fileInfo, req, res) {
      var origFilename = fileInfo.name;

      // optimisticly get the extension
      var parts = origFilename.split('.'),
          extension = parts[parts.length-1];

      // Using a local timestamp + user id in the filename (you might want to change this)
      var newFilename = (new Date()).getTime()+'.'+extension;
      return newFilename;
    }
  }
};
```